# Arduino Serial1

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I'm using an [Arduino Micro](https://store.arduino.cc/collections/boards/products/arduino-micro). When I use "Serial.write", etc. with the Arduino's IDE serial monitor, everything is working fine.

However, when I try to read or send data via "Serial1", I get nothing. "Serial1" is supposed to use 0 and 1, RX and TX, respectively.

Do I need to connect these pins through a USB converter or are they connected on the boards USB converter?

Here is the code:

```
Void setup(){ Serial1.begin(4800); }
Void loop(){ Serial1.prrint('X'); }
```

Comment: Please show us your code ;-)

Comment: Void setup(){
Serial1.begin(4800);

 }

Void loop(){

Serial1.prrint('X');
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there so anyone can easily see it. This is usually considered a best practice on SO, it would be great if you used it as well ;-)

Comment: Is "`prrint`" actually in the code? Does it compile?

Comment: And what about "`Void`" (upper case "V")?

Comment: OK, we will never know. The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 8 years ago"*

Answer (score 8):

The only serial port connected to the USB that the serial monitor can read from is *Serial*.

*Serial1*, *Serial2*, and *Serial3* are all logic level serial and will not show up on the Arduino serial monitor.

If you want to see the output from these on your computer, it will require extra hardware.

Answer (score 6):

Serial is the only serial port connected to USB. So serial monitor can access only that port. If you need Serial1 or Serial2 to be accessed by serial monitor, then you should use 'USB to TTL Serial Cable' and connect this to RX and TX pins of the arduino's **Serial1** port.
Please visit link for USB to TTL Serial Cable,  [enter link description here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12977)

Answer (score 4):

"Serial1" in Arduino Micro is *physically* connected to the TX and RX pins (TTL), and "Serial" is just a "virtual port" which you can read using Arduino IDE's *Serial Monitor*. That’s why Arduino Micro is a little different from another, such as [Arduino Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Official) or [Arduino Pro Mini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Official).

If you use Serial and Serial1, you can approach this advantage, upload code using USB and make a connection through [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) (using HC06 connected to physical pins) without disconnecting the USB cable and powered both devices (Arduino Micro and Bluetooth).

If you can't upload code to your Arduino Micro sometimes, press the Arduino Micro's reset button, release it, and press the upload button in Arduino IDE's.
"virtual port" sometimes needs to restart and connect using USB.

This is from Arduino's documentation website:

> ...Serial: 0 (RX) and 1 (TX). Used to receive (RX) and transmit (TX) **TTL serial data using the ATmega32U4 hardware serial capability**. Note that on the Micro, the Serial class refers to USB (CDC) communication; for TTL serial on pins 0 and 1, use the Serial1 class.

Answer (score 1):

You said it right. Serial1 is the RX and TX pin, while Serial is a virtual interface between the computer and Arduino. I have used the TX and RX pins for a wireless module, and if you *need* to use Serial1, it would have to occupy pins 0 and 1, and **switch from DLINE to UART on your board**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go to tool/board: and select Arduino Mega (or other board with multiply serial ports) or it won't work, because the Uno only has one Serial communication port (aka The TX and RX pins on pins on 1 and 0)! Write 1,2 or 3 depending on what TX and RX pins you are using on the Board. The mega has a whole set of extra pins for Serial 1,2 and 3, for example:

Arduino Uno (etc):

```
Serial.begin(9600)
Serial.write("testing")
```

Arduino Mega:

```
Serial1.begin(9600) // <{or what even baud rate you should use}
Serial1.write("testing")
```

or

```
Serial2.begin(9600)
Serial2.write("testing")
```

or

```
Serial3.begin(9600)
Serial3.write("testing")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
Void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(4800);  // 9600....
}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available())
    {
        int a = Serial.read();
        Serial.Writeln(a);
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.Writeln("Error");
    }
}
```

Open the serial monitor with the icon placed in right corner of Arduino IDE. It will be available if you connect the Arduino with PC.

Comment: This will not compile. It obviously hasn't been tested. It repeats the incorrect code from the question (most likely retyped, with an introduction of three typos).

Comment: I don't think there is a "Writeln" function, and if there were it would be all lowercase (writeln). There is the *[Serial.println](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/)* function. Here is [a list of functions for Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/).

Comment: But the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score -1):

When you open the Arduino IDE, write this code block:

```
Void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available())
    {
        char get = Serial.read();
        Serial.Write(get);
    }
}
```

Select the Arduino 9600 port and write something. If you get your written text, your Arduino is ready for serial communication.

Comment: This will not compile. It obviously hasn't been tested. It repeats some of the incorrect code from the question (most likely retyped, with an introduction of three typos).

Answer (score -1):

`Serial1` is the wrong class for pin 0 and pin 1. You should use `Serial` class.

> Do I need to connect these pins through a USB converter or are they connected on the boards USB converter?

It makes no difference for Serial class.

Comment: This is wrong, Serial1 is used for the RX and TX pins.

Comment: This may be true for another Arduino model, but this question is for Arduino Micro.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define Serial1 by using SoftwareSerial class from SoftwareSerial library, google and download the library:

The code should be something like this:

```
// Example
SoftwareSerial Serial1(9, 10); // RX and TX, respectively

Void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(4800); // Here is your New serial
    Serial.begin(9600); // This is where Arduino is connected to your PC
}

Void loop() {
    // Code goes Here
}
```

Comment: This will not compile. It obviously hasn't been tested. It repeats some of the incorrect code from the question (most likely retyped, with an introduction of three typos).